# How to override "gift card added to cart"

Tags: magento2, gift-card

I need to override the action fired when a customer sets a gift card in his cart.  I need to apply a custom check against an external web service about the validity of the gift card applied.

Which is the file that I need to override?

Seems that I need to override this file:

`vendor/magento/module-gift-card-account/Model/Service/GiftCardAccountManagement.php`

Where I need to write my override inside my app folder?

Comment: Did you got the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a small example how to override Core Model file in `Magento 2`.

**Step 1**

Create a `di.xml` file in a following directory `Vendor/Module/etc`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Rewrite\Catalog\Product" />
</config>
```

**Step 2**

The step2 to overriding or rewriting Magento2 model is to create a `Product.php` helper file in the following directory `Vendor/Module/Model/Rewrite/Catalog`

```
<?php
/**
* Catalog Product Rewrite Model
*
*
*/
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Rewrite\Catalog;
class Product extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
{
public function __construct()
{
echo "Overrding/ Rewrite Working"; die();
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The di.xml was the missing part!

Comment: @AndreaCrevola Please approve my answer...